# Wifi and cellular data keep turning off by itself.

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, mobile-data, alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

I have an Alcatel onetouch fiercexl.  All of a sudden my wifi and Metro PCS cellular data keep turning off.  It only stays on for a few minutes. If try to use any app or go on the internet by the time I load it it says no internet connection.  I use my data if I'm not home and wifi at home and they both keep turning off.  Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Android Samsung S5.  Wifi kept turning itself off. Very annoying.  I had the smart network switch on or off...didn't matter.  I discovered that I had the ATT Smart WiFi app enabled.  I turned that off and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely should not happen. Few things to try:

- Did you install / Do you use any program that can change these settings? Something like app for changing the status by your location or by time or by its profile. It might be some application that came reinstalled with your phone (do not know what was there)
- Is there newer version of firmware for your phone? If so, consider upgrading. This might be radio ROM issue.
- As last resort on your side, you could try to perform factory reset on your phone (however you LOSE ALL YOUR DATA) to see if the problem persists afterwards.

If nothing above helps you it might be hardware problem and you should return your phone for warranty repair.

Answer (score 0):

[Please note, this is a Windows phone and this is an Android forum.  So this answer will quickly disappear.  If it's useful, please up-vote and/or mark the question as answered?  I could do with the reputation points.]

According to the [Alcatel One Touch Fierce XL Manual](https://theinformr.co.uk/upload/manuals/alcatel-one-touch-fierce-xl-manual.pdf), as well as a full factory reset it is possible to reset the browser, camera and storage separately.

But before that, have you tried simply turning the phone off, waiting a little, then turning it on again?  [It is, after all, a Windows phone :-) ]

If the suggestions by [Aries](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/198531/aries) fail, you will probably have to try a Factory Reset.  (Alcatel require this before contacting them, see the Troubleshooting section of the Manual.)

First save all your data:

1. Make a note of the email account and password you used as the phone's first account.
2. Under Settings->Personal there is an option to backup the phone's internal data to Google Servers (if you registered a Google account).
3. Be aware that you will have to back up any documents, music or pictures separately.  Plugging your phone into your computer using a USB lead (the charging lead?) is one way of doing that.
4. Make sure your emails are safe by checking you can access all of them independently (on your computer or from your email provider's web interface).  If necessary, Forward them to your email account.
5. Make a note of any Apps you've downloaded from Windows Store.  The Store should have a record of any you have paid for. and will allow you to restore them later.

Then do a Factory Reset from Settings->Personal->Backup & Reset.  Or, with the phone turned off, hold Volume Up and Power keys until the screen lights up.

Finally, log in using the original email and password, restore the settings from Google and copy back your music, photos and any other files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post but i thought i'd still post this if anyone comes across this while having similar problems...
I solved this by removing the SIM card and putting it back in.
Hope this helps